# Cocos2d javascript android crash

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I have a simple app, but it crashes on any android device or simulator that i am targeting. It runs ok on iOS and WEB though. Using the cocos2djs 3.7.1, NDK r10e. Here is a stack trace and i can not figure out what is wrong:

```
    D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052): 
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052): {
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.supports_vertex_array_object: false
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.supports_ATITC: false
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.supports_S3TC: false
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x-3.7
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: false
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.supports_PVRTC: false
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  cocos2d.x.build_type: DEBUG
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.renderer: PowerVR SGX 544MP
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.supports_ETC1: true
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.version: 2.1 INTEL-10.6.31
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.supports_NPOT: true
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.max_texture_units: 16
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.vendor: Imagination Technologies
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052):  gl.max_texture_size: 16384
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052): }
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052): 
D/cocos2d-x debug info( 3052): 
F/libc    ( 3052): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=128), thread 3067 (Thread-153)
I/ActivityManager(  546): Displayed com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler/org.cocos2dx.javascript.AppActivity: +183ms (total +6s600ms)
I/DEBUG   (  154): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  154): Build fingerprint: 'andy/andy/andy:4.2.2/JDQ39E/eng.developer.20150116.074207:userdebug/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  154): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  154): pid: 3052, tid: 3067, name: Thread-153  >>> com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler <<<
I/DEBUG   (  154): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 128 (?), fault addr 00000000
D/SettingsProvider(  546): User 0 external modification to /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db; event=8
D/SettingsProvider(  546): User 0 updating our caches for /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
I/DEBUG   (  154):     eax b7aa4898  ebx 98c13934  ecx b7aa4898  edx 961e89f0
I/DEBUG   (  154):     esi 961ecf34  edi 961e8b94
I/DEBUG   (  154):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
I/DEBUG   (  154):     eip 97ffd06f  ebp 961e88e8  esp 961e8260  flags 00010282
I/DEBUG   (  154): 
I/DEBUG   (  154): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #00  pc 01bb606f  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (_ZN7cocos2d8MathUtil14multiplyMatrixEPKDv4_fS3_PS1_+105)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #01  pc 01a67083  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (cocos2d::Mat4::multiply(cocos2d::Mat4 const&, cocos2d::Mat4 const&, cocos2d::Mat4*)+163)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #02  pc 01a66fd8  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (cocos2d::Mat4::multiply(cocos2d::Mat4 const&)+44)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #03  pc 01a8755d  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (cocos2d::Mat4::operator*=(cocos2d::Mat4 const&)+37)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #04  pc 01a897ea  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (cocos2d::Director::multiplyMatrix(cocos2d::MATRIX_STACK_TYPE, cocos2d::Mat4 const&)+98)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #05  pc 01a89c9c  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (cocos2d::Director::setProjection(cocos2d::Director::Projection)+512)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #06  pc 01a889ce  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (cocos2d::Director::setGLDefaultValues()+232)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #07  pc 01a88f55  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (cocos2d::Director::setOpenGLView(cocos2d::GLView*)+419)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #08  pc 0096d0b0  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit+211)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #09  pc 0001ae60  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+80)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #10  pc 0006f623  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+723)
I/DEBUG   (  154): 
I/DEBUG   (  154): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8220  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8224  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8228  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e822c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8230  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8234  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8238  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e823c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8240  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8244  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8248  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e824c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8250  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8254  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8258  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e825c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #00  961e8260  402ab600  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8264  402ab600  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8268  402ab600  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e826c  402ab600  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8270  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8274  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8278  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e827c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8280  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8284  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8288  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e828c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8290  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8294  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8298  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e829c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #01  961e88f0  b7aa4898  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e88f4  961e89f0  [stack:3067]
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e88f8  b7aa4898  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e88fc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8900  00000001  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8904  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8908  40000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e890c  b7aa3e70  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8910  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8914  98c13934  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8918  961e8938  [stack:3067]
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e891c  97eadfd8  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (cocos2d::Mat4::multiply(cocos2d::Mat4 const&)+44)
I/DEBUG   (  154):     #02  961e8920  b7aa4898  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8924  961e89f0  [stack:3067]
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8928  b7aa4898  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e892c  0453e10c  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8930  961ecf34  
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8934  98c13934  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e8938  961e8958  [stack:3067]
I/DEBUG   (  154):          961e893c  97ece55d  /data/app-lib/com.mkdigitalsolutions.puzzler-1/libcocos2djs.so (cocos2d::Mat4::operator*=(cocos2d::Mat4 const&)+37)
```

My main.js code looks something like this:

```
cc.game.onStart = function(){
    if(!cc.sys.isNative && document.getElementById("cocosLoading")) //If referenced loading.js, please remove it
        document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("cocosLoading"));

    LibraryIntegration.iniAnalytics();

    cc.view.adjustViewPort(true);

    if (cc.sys.isNative)
    {
        var searchPaths = jsb.fileUtils.getSearchPaths();

        // ipad retina
        if (cc.view.getFrameSize().width >= 1536 && cc.view.getFrameSize().height >= 1536)
        {
            cc.log("large");
            searchPaths.push("res/resolutions/large");
            searchPaths.push("src");
        }
        else if (cc.view.getFrameSize().width >= 640 && cc.view.getFrameSize().height >= 640) //iphone hd or above and android high res screens
        {
            cc.log("Medium");

            searchPaths.push("res/resolutions/medium");
            searchPaths.push("src");
        }
        else
        {
            cc.log("small");
            searchPaths.push("res/resolutions/small");
            searchPaths.push("src");
        }

        jsb.fileUtils.setSearchPaths(searchPaths);
    }
    else
    {
        cc.view.resizeWithBrowserSize(true);
    }

    cc.view.setDesignResolutionSize(640, 960, cc.ResolutionPolicy.FIXED_WIDTH);

cc.eventManager.addCustomListener(cc.game.EVENT_HIDE, function(){
        //onEnterBackground handler
        cc.log("Did enter bg");
        var difference = differenceBetweenDates(0);
        recordTotalTimePlayed(difference.diff);
        recordSessionTimePlayed(difference.diff);
    });

    cc.eventManager.addCustomListener(cc.game.EVENT_SHOW, function(){
        //onEnterForeground handler
        cc.log("Did enter fg");
        recordTimeForSession();
    });

    recordTimeForSession();

    cc.LoaderScene.preload(main_menu_resources, function () {
        cc.director.runScene(new MainMenuScene());
    }, this);

    setStarsForLevels();

};
cc.game.run();
```

If i comment mainMenuScene loading lines - it runs fine with a black screen. My main scene code:

```
    var MainMenuScene = cc.Scene.extend({
    onEnter:function () {
        this._super();

        var mainMenuUI = ccs.load(mainMenuRes.MainMenuUI, "res/");
        //mainMenuUI.node.ignoreAnchorPointForPosition(false);
        mainMenuUI.node.setAnchorPoint(0.5, 0.5);
        mainMenuUI.node.setPosition(cc.director.getVisibleOrigin().x + cc.director.getVisibleSize().width * 0.5, cc.director.getVisibleOrigin().y + cc.director.getVisibleSize().height * 0.5);
        this.addChild(mainMenuUI.node);

        var play = mainMenuUI.node.getChildByName("Play");
        cc.assert(cc.sys.isObjectValid(play), "Play button not valid");
        play.addTouchEventListener(function (sender, type) {

            if(type != ccui.Widget.TOUCH_ENDED) return;

            Redirect.goToEpochSelection();
        }, this);

        var stats = mainMenuUI.node.getChildByName("stats");
        cc.assert(cc.sys.isObjectValid(stats), "Stats button not valid");
        stats.addTouchEventListener(function (sender, type) {

            if(type != ccui.Widget.TOUCH_ENDED) return;

            Redirect.goToStats();
        }, this);

        var color = mainMenuUI.node.getChildByName("Color");
        cc.assert(cc.sys.isObjectValid(color), "Color not valid");
        color.setContentSize(5000, 5000);
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

**UPDATE:**

So i think i found the reason but not the solution yet. I was building for 3 architectures for android - APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi x86, if i build only for armeabi - crash is gone but it just works on that architecture emulators or devices....